# Why is this constructor not giving an incomplete type error?

Tags: c++, types, language-lawyer

I have two files test.h and main.cpp as shown below:

### test.h

```
#include <memory>

class TestImpl;

template <typename... T>
void createConnection(T&&... Args)
{
    // 1. Why is this working if the constructor is in cpp?
    std::unique_ptr<TestImpl> pimpl(new TestImpl(std::forward<T>(Args)...));
    std::cout << "Done..." << std::endl;

    // 2. Why is this not working if the constructor call has no issues?
    pimpl->sayHello();
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.h"

class TestImpl
{
public:
    TestImpl(const std::string& first, const std::string& second)
        : _first(first)
        , _second(second)
    {
    }

    void sayHello()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello ... " << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string _first;
    std::string _second;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    createConnection("ABC", "DEF");
    return 0;
}
```

As evident from the comments my main question is why the constructor call is not giving an error "invalid use of incomplete type 'class TestImpl'...". For reference I am using GCC 5.2, with no specific flags.

Comment: Is it really incomplete at the point of template instantiation?

Comment: The reason is that yo used constructor in template, and template is instantiated when it is used and at that point full definition of `TestImpl` is know to compiler.

Comment: @Marek R sayHello function is also used inside template so could not understand your point

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/_YBvsc).

Comment: I tried to reproduce but I can't. [GCC 5.2 on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lu9O9R96ylFSTVGw) rejects it. The TU is laid out exactly like your sample would be.

Comment: @n.m. What do you mean "not reproducible", your link fails to compile with the exact same error :D

Comment: @n.m. Isn't that exactly what the question says? Constructor does not complain but member function does.

Comment: I can reproduce in http://rextester.com for gcc but not for clang. Seems to be a compiler issue.

Comment: @StoryTeller the exact same point - you get the same error as the OP.

Comment: @jdehesa didn't find the "member function does" part

Comment: @V0ldek - Please read the OP carefully `// 1. Why this is working if constructor is in cpp` / *"why constructor call is **not** giving error "*- The OP is asking why it **works**. Not why it *fails*.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, and your sample **works** with the constructor, but **does not work** on the `sayHello` method - the exact unexpected behavior the question is about. Same goes for @n.m. .

Comment: Or in other words, why does it compile in gcc if we comment the `pimpl->sayHello();` line? (it doesn't in clang)

Comment: @StoryTeller : I agree with what V0ldek is telling and the intent of this question why constructor is not failing even though sayHello call is giving error

Comment: D'oh. Serves me right for faffing about with the example myself. I was checking Clang too. That one failed https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dd57euUfreYviXwx

Comment: I added the language lawyer tag since compilers are having a difference of opinion here, and the answer depends on the word of the standard. Please roll back if you disagree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply put, GCC doesn't have to reject your program, and Clang doesn't have to accept it. It's ill-formed, no diagnostic required. Since `TestImpl` is incomplete, your template is in violation of

> **[[temp.res]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#8.3)**
>
> ... The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not
>     depend on a template parameter, or
> - the interpretation of such a construct in the hypothetical instantiation is different from the interpretation of the
>     corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the template.

One could argue that the constructor being called is dependent, but the class name is surely not!

In our case, a hypothetical instantiation with a pack of two strings immediately after the template definition will give different results than at the point of instantiation in your program. This is because the class name itself (which is, again, not dependent) has different meaning in the two contexts.

It's not a valid template definition. But GCC is exercising some leeway here, since no diagnostic is required, and plowing on.

---

This is succinctly summarized in the note under the bullets, which while not normative, describes your case:

> This can happen in situations including the following:
>
> - a type used in a non-dependent name is incomplete at the point at which a template is defined but is complete at the point at which an
>     instantiation is performed, or

Comment: [8.5.1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8.5.1) is more straightforward.

Comment: @xskxzr - It is. But I stopped reading at `Note` :). Will add it.

Comment: The standard wording in [temp.dep] make me curious: *In an expression **of the form**:
`postfix-expression ( expression-listopt )`*. It is not said in *In a function-call expression:[...]*. I wonder what is the "intent" of the standard here?

Comment: @Oliv - A functor object would fit the form but won't be a function call expression per-se, I think. Not sure however.

Comment: @Oliv Postfix-expressions that are only unqualified-ids includes much more than just function calls, stuff like functors, creating temporaries with type names, template names and whatnot.

Comment: @StoryTeller Digging a litle bit I found [over.call] *It implements the function call syntax*... so this was probably the intent: one way of interpreting is it implements function call syntax but this is not a function-call-expression since the postfix expression in [expr.call] must have pointer to function type. I am filling as a doctor of the inquisition:)!

Comment: @PasserBy Not sure we understand each other! I don't get your comment.

Comment: I am not sure gcc is wrong. Only considering the grammar and not the semantic, a postfix-expression can be a primary expression, which can be a name, so an identifier. By saying *form* in [dep.name] they are maybe insisting that this is a grammar rule, in which case gcc would be right and clang wrong.

Comment: @Oliv - There is no right or wrong, it's ill formed NDR. Furthermore, context matters. This isn't a function call expression. It's a *new expression*.

Comment: @StoryTeller : To be frank your answer contains such difficult language that I am unable to grasp it.Can there be simple to understand explanation ?

Comment: @Kapil - The standard doesn't require a diagnostic for this type of error. So GCC doesn't provide one.